# Preventing Node TypeError crashing app

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, request

Using the simple [request.js http client](https://github.com/mikeal/request) I've noticed that sometimes a simple `TypeError` can crash the whole node app. Taking one of the examples:

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
})
```

Now, take the hypothetical (in Google's case!) situation where Google fails to respond and the connection just hangs then times out. This code simply crashes the node app as `response` is undefined so `response.statusCode` cannot be read. This bubbles up to the event loop and triggers the crash with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
```

What's the simplest way I can prevent this from happening? I could add a check for the value of `error` before checking for the `statusCode` for example:

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // do stuff
        }
    }
})
```

But I'd rather not add unnecessary lines to the app if possible. I may be missing something obvious here! Any pointers greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: This is what you get.
Verbose answer:

- Always check for errors
- Always check your data

So, something like this is pretty OK:

```
if (!error && body) {
  //do whatever you want with your body
}

if (!error && response) {
  //do whatever you want with response
}
```

You have to ensure that object exists before trying to access it(in cases where existence of object is not guaranteed). Also, take a look at [maybe2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/maybe2) module. With this module you can write somethis like that:

```
if (!error && maybe(response).getOrElse({}).statusCode == 200) {
  //your code here
}
```

- Use node.js cluster mode, supervisor modules like [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever) and/or load balancing proxy like nginx in front of your app. This way, if one request fails other requests would be fulfilled by other instances of your app.
- Be prepared to handle errors at client side and repeat requests on fail.